# SSE operation on 4 arrays of integer size that code in C

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

Sorry for the previous in-descriptive question. Please allow me to rephrase the question again:

the setup:

I need to do ADD and some bit wise operations of 4 32bit value from 4 arrays at same time using SSE, all the element in these 4 arrays are integer size(32 bit). The result goes to the 5th array.

so my question is:

1. what header files and compiler flags i need to include such that i can run the SSE using C?
2. Does the example code provide by Paul stills works?

Another question, if I need to read last bit from integer A, and first bit from integer B, and replace the last bit and first bit in integer C by the values I just read, can i use SSE here? or is there any fast way to do it? instead of 3 access in normal case?

Again, apologize for previous post, and thanks for any input...^_^

Comment: Voting to reopen as this is potentially a good question - we just need the OP to come back and provide some more detail about the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that:

- you want to add corresponding ints from 4 input arrays and store the sums in a fifth (output) array
- ints are 32 bits
- array size (N) is a multiple of 4
- all arrays are 16 byte aligned

then this should do it:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

const size_t N = 4096;  // size of input/output arrays

int32_t array0[N];      // 4 x input arrays
int32_t array1[N];
int32_t array2[N];
int32_t array3[N];
int32_t array_sum[N];   // output array

for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 4)
{
    __m128i v0 = _mm_load_si128(&array0[i]); // load 4 x vectors of 4 x int
    __m128i v1 = _mm_load_si128(&array1[i]);
    __m128i v2 = _mm_load_si128(&array2[i]);
    __m128i v3 = _mm_load_si128(&array3[i]);
    __m128i vsum = _mm_add_epi32(v0, v1);    // sum vectors
    __m128i vsum = _mm_add_epi32(vsum, v2);
    __m128i vsum = _mm_add_epi32(vsum, v3);
    _mm_store_si128(&array_out[i], vsum);    // store sum
}
```